# Convert .bat to .exe without depending on cmd.exe

Tags: c++, batch-file, cmd, converters

I have a bat to execute all files in a folder every 15 seconds. I need to make it .exe to run it as a hidden application.
I have converted it to .exe with bat to exe converter and other programs, and I see that in all of them, when I execute the .exe, for example, Load.exe, automatically start a cmd.exe  at the same time. If I kill Load.exe it still continues to run, until I kill cmd.exe.

So, can I make an .exe from a .bat without depending on a cmd.exe?

Comment: I see you've languaged-tagged this as C++. If you know that language then use it to port your batch file to an exe. `#include <iostream>` and go from there.

Comment: You could make C++ program that calls the system using `system` function. I don't know if that depends on cmd.exe or not.

Comment: What does the batch file do? That would determine how easy (or difficult) it it so translate. But it can certainly be written in C or C++.

Comment: The batch executes all files on a determiate folder every 15 secongs. I use this to send "orders" remotely to other computers and then they execute these orders locally, by this bat. I'm not good at C++ that why I was asking if this was posible, because I have other processes, that kill cmd.exe continuously, that's why I need to made it .exe

Comment: Your computers' operating environment sounds horrifying.  That said, what you want is doable in C++, but you'll have to learn C++ and just a bit of the Windows API to get the job done.  Don't use `system()` as that just calls `cmd.exe`.  You'll have to use whatever Windows gives you that corresponds to `fork` and `execv`.

Comment: You can use `CMDOW` to hide a batch window.  It's classed as a hacking tool by some AV programs but it should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Short but correct answer: no, you can not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it depends on CMD or not (probably it doesn't), but you can use C++ function system to execute each line of your .bat file.

Do it something like :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  system("<batch command goes here>");
  return 0;
}
```

Simultaneously, you can add each line of .bat file to system function and execute it as a CPP/C program.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I have tried and it also starts cmd.exe

Comment: If that doesn't work then I'm afraid the only way it would be possible to do that is by learning what each batch command that you want to impliment is doing and write a standalone C Code for it.

Comment: Thank you. Finally thats what I did.